# How to use @Autowired service, in an object created with the factory / strategy pattern (created at runtime)?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, strategy-pattern

Consider an interface `Action`, and 2 implementing classes: `StupidAction` and `SmartAction`.

`SmartAction` needs to use another service, but because an `Action` is created at runtime, the `@Autowired` annotation doesn't work (the service is null).

Is it wrong to use the Strategy pattern with **Spring**? Is there a nice solution for this issue?

I could set "StupidAction" as a service as well, and not instantiate it. I could as well pass the autowired services to "doSomething" in method parameters. But both solutions are really dirty.

Some code example:

```
public interface Action {
    void doSomething();
}

public class StupidAction implements Action{

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;  // THIS IS NULL. because StupidAction is instanciated at runtime.

    public void doSomething(){
        myService.changeSomething()
    }
}

//Pseudo code
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class WorkflowController {

    @GetMapping("")
    ResponseEntity someAPI() {  
        Action action = new SmartAction(); //create on runtime
        action.doSomething(); //NullPointerExc
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some relevant code to show?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "created at runtime". Everything is "created at runtime".

Comment: @Michael you are right, I mean after Spring has done all the injections and instanciations

Comment: i don't see why you wouldn't make the SmartAction a spring-managed bean and autowire it into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bean from the context by name dynamically using [BeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html):

```
@Service
public class Service {

  @Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;

  public void foo(){
    DynamicBean bean = beanFactory.getBean("bean_name", DynamicBean.class)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the @Autowired BeanFactory will be null as well. won't it?

Comment: Spring will Autowire beanFactory.

Comment: I tried this solution: I added @Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory; inside SmartAction class, but beanFactory is null....

Answer (score -2):

You can get the bean from a Util service which is ApplicationContextAware.

```
@Service
public class BeanUtility implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
    public static <T extends Object> T getMyBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

The controller implementation as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class WorkflowController {

    @Autowired
    BeanUtility beanUtility;

    @GetMapping("action")
    ResponseEntity someAPI() {
        MyService myService = BeanUtility.getMyBean(MyService.class); // use the util class to get a Bean of your choice
        Action action = new SmartAction(myService); // Constructor based DI
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(action.doSomething(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Followed by the implementation of SmartAction class as below:

```
@Service
public class SmartAction implements Action{

    private MyService myService;

    public SmartAction(MyService myService){
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return "Smart action : " + myService.changeSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible approach. Why go through all the trouble of using `BeanUtility`? `WorkflowController` is already a bean, inject the `ApplicationContext` in it directly. Or if you still want to use the `BeanUtility`, just use it as a bean since you've `@Autowired` it into the controller. Why would you want those methods to be `static` in this case?